# PHP : Undefined index

Tags: php, if-statement, get

I have a Drupal site, although I assume this is just a PHP issue rather than a Drupal specific problem.  The snippet below....

```
if($_GET['orderby'] == 'popular' || !isset($_GET['orderby'])) { $output .= 'Popular'; }
```

Works fine when the URL looks like this...

```
www.mydomain.com/mypage?orderby=popular
```

but if the URL is…

```
www.mydomain.com/mypage
```

then I get an error…

```
Undefined index: orderby in…
```

What am I doing wrong?  As far as I can see I am checking if 'orderby' exists correctly.

Comment: what are you trying to do ? are you checking if the `$_GET['orderby']` is having popular? or checking if it is empty?

Answer (score 3):

Swap conditions in your `if` :

```
if(!isset($_GET['orderby']) || $_GET['orderby'] == 'popular' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if `$_GET['orderby']` has the value `'popular'`. But the thing is that `$_GET['orderby']` is undefined (when there are no value assigned to it).

So the PHP interprets this as:

```
if("underfined index of $_GET array" == 'popular' ....
```

**That's the actual issue.**

You would have to something like: (yes, you could optimize code. But this is mostly for clarifications of what the issue is)

```
if (isset($_GET['orderby'])) //Is $_GET['orderby'] defined?

    //It's defined. Check the value of it...
    if($_GET['orderby'] == 'popular') {
        code...            
    }
}
```